# How to connect Selenium Webdriver(TestNG) with MS SQL Server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone of guys mentioned the step by step procedure to connect Selenium webdriver using TestNG with MS SQl Server?

Comment: Can you share your efforts.

Comment: @AhmadOdeh Can you consider sharing your work please? Thanks

Comment: Put some efforts  by yourself to search and implement the content

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sample code to connect Selenium WebDriver to Server :

```
     @Test

      public void connection() {

  //Loading the required JDBC Driver class
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  

            //Creating a connection to the database
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://artOfTesting.com/testDB","userName","password");

            //Executing SQL query and fetching the result
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String sqlStr = "select * from testTable";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlStr);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            }       }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Dear RNS,


Thanks for your feedback,
Can you please mention what files need to be downloaded and what are the configuration that needs to done on eclipse before running your script